# Passing variables to nested jQuery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got two input fields that each dynamically generate a small image with a red cross when they are filled with text. The idea is that the user can clear the text by clicking on that image. The javascript code is exactly the same with the only difference being the **alt value** of the image and the **name attribute** of the input box.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $("input[type='text']").keyup(function(){
        var alt = "clear"+$(this).attr("name");
        if($(this).val() && !$("img[alt='"+alt+"']").length){
            $(this).after("<img src='images/cross.png' alt='"+alt+"'/>");
        }
    });

    $(document).on('click', 'img[alt="clearsource"]' , function(){
        $( "input[name='source']" ).val('');
        $(this).remove();
    });

    $(document).on('click', 'img[alt="clearlocation"]' , function(){
        $( "input[name='location']" ).val('');
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="source" placeholder="Source" /><br />
        <input type="text" name="location" placeholder="Location" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I wanted to make a reusable function through which I can pass two variables, and then call it twice. This is my attempt but it's not working. Can someone please help? Is it a scope issue?

Here is the JSFiddle version: https://jsfiddle.net/2bk86w4y/

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $("input[type='text']").keyup(function(){
        var alt = "clear"+$(this).attr("name");
        if($(this).val() && !$("img[alt='"+alt+"']").length){
            $(this).after("<img src='images/cross.png' alt='"+alt+"'/>");
        }
    });

    // == The function below replaces the duplicate functions in the previous code block. 
    // == Unfortunately it doesn't work. Please help :(

    function clearBox(inputname,imagealt){
        $(document).on("click", "img[alt='"+imagealt+"']" , function(){
            $( "input[name='"+inputname+"']"  ).val('');
            $(this).remove();
        });
    }

    clearBox("clearsource","source");
    clearBox("clearlocation","location");
});
</script>
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: a [mcve] would be great!

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Those variables, `inputname` and `imagealt`,  should have scope to that function now and be available to look up. It seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/1be5wpte/

Comment: Hey guys, I updated the code in a simpler example with the same problem to give you a better idea. I hope this helps! Looking forward to your support :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got your parameters the wrong way round.

https://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/2bk86w4y/1/

```
clearBox("clearsource", "source");
clearBox("clearlocation", "location"); 

// should be...

clearBox("source", "clearsource");
clearBox("location", "clearlocation");
```

Comment: Dave, you are AWESOME! I'm laughing here because of how STUPID the mistake is xD. Thank you SO MUCH! I really really appreciate it buddy!